# FireStore integration Error in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

Error:

> (29, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_aagdpcrog7mo1w9s4rl127jc9$_run_closure3@657a3629] on root project 'Firestore-Phonebook-master' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>   Open File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with your build.gradle.

Take a look at this repository:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

and take care, that your build.gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If that is not the problem, please add more information about your exception.